# Taking screenshots from PDF file with Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, groovy, inputstream, pdfbox, katalon-studio

I use `pdfbox` to generate images from all the pages of a `PDF` file. File is given in an URL.

```
public String Pdf2Image(String html, WebDriver driver){
    URL url=new URL(GlobalVariable.url);
    HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    InputStream is=connection.getInputStream();

    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(is);
    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
        BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
        ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, GlobalVariable.fileAzon + "-" + (page+1) + ".png", 300);
    }
    document.close();
}
```

It doesn't work for PDF files, which text content couldn't be copied and printing is disabled. I get following error message during execution. I couldn't get `InputStream`.

**UPDATE:** Example file: http://aplaidshirt.epizy.com/samplePDF.pdf

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
    at com.pdf.reader.ReadPdfFromBrowser.invokeMethod(ReadPdfFromBrowser.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.java:50)
    at print.run(print:10)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1578260748461.run(TempTestCase1578260748461.groovy:23)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1124)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2603)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:2574)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:219)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1222)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1122)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument$load.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.pdf.reader.ReadPdfFromBrowser.Pdf2Image(ReadPdfFromBrowser.groovy:72)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Please share an example file.

Comment: Your file is likely empty or not a PDF, same as in the other issue.

Comment: @mkl : I can't download that one, but I tried to reproduce it: https://gofile.io/?c=WYPqpZ

Comment: @mkl : Hosted example file: http://aplaidshirt.epizy.com/samplePDF.pdf

Comment: According to your stack trace the error occurred during `PDDocument.load`. Thus, I tried to load your example file. Unfortunately, no error happened. Thus, this might be an issue in your version of PDFBox which meanwhile is fixed. Which PDFBox version do you use?

Comment: @mkl : I use version 2.0.18 and I can reproduce it also in WebDriver with this code: https://pastebin.com/vrz5j8XG I got same error message.

Comment: Have you tried to write the contents of `is` into some file instead of making PDFBox load from there? And then opening that file?

Comment: I can repaet your error. Exception is throw in BaseParser.readLine (seqSource.isEOF()) called from  COSParser.parseHeader. In my header I have value such as: "...please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support" then.

Comment: @MariuszW : I use also browser in normal mode.

Comment: @plaidshirt - I think that there is some problem with your pdf file. It has nothing to do with browser - in code https://pastebin.com/vrz5j8XG You can remove driver and result is the same (your file don't work and other e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.00999.pdf works).  I have found in jira this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4443  - but can you try to create another example pdf file?

Comment: When I don't download the PDF first but access the URL with PDFDebugger directly I get the same error msg. A test of that URL with Xenu's Link Sleuth shows that the MIME type is text/html, and it has a link to a Javascript URL.

Comment: Yes, pdf file is ok when used from disk. When called from code (HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();) - response from server is javascriipt "script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"  which is run in browser and reload pdf - but in pdfbox javascript is not run ...so no pdf in stream only html.

Comment: Thus, essentially @TilmanHausherr's first comment hit home, the file is not a PDF but some Javascript code...

Comment: I see you also created an issue in JIRA and Andreas answered you, and of course he had the same result. (I did not "warn" him) I suspect that the service you are using is taking precautions to avoid being used as a classic file server.